# PHPExcel, auto resize row height

Tags: php, phpexcel

I would like to display the whole text on a generated .xls with PHPExcel 1.8.0. Currently, the cell (actually the whole row) isn't resized even though it didn't set any row height.

here are some screenshots :

[image: What i got (generated)]

[image: What i would like (obtained on double clicking the "resize row height")]

Here is my code :

```
$this->xls->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension($this->row)->setRowHeight(-1);

$this->xls->getActiveSheet()->getStyle("A".$this->row.":F".$this->row)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

$this->xls->getActiveSheet()->getCell("A".$this->row)->setValue(APPLICATION_ACADEMY);
$this->xls->getActiveSheet()->getCell("B".$this->row)->setValue(date("d/m/Y"));
$this->xls->getActiveSheet()->getCell("C".$this->row)->setValue($fait['nature'] === null ? $fait['codeNature'] : $fait['nature']);
$this->xls->getActiveSheet()->getCell("D".$this->row)->setValue($fait['etablissement']);
```

I used what i already found on stack (setTextWrap / setRowHeight(-1)) but it has no effect

Anyone got an idea ? Is it even possible ? thanks.

Comment: did you find a fix? this also does not work for me.

Comment: I am also using v 1.8.0 and `-1` didn't work for me. That is neither `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getDefaultRowDimension()->setRowHeight(-1);` nor `
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(8)->setRowHeight(0);` worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Below is working for me but its for single row:

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(1)->setRowHeight(-1);
```

To change height of all rows to auto you can do:

```
foreach($xls->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimensions() as $rd) { 
    $rd->setRowHeight(-1); 
}
```

Comment: setRowHeight = -1 also breaks the image ratio